# Use scala to create an interactive shell

Tags: scala, shell, console

I am teaching myself Scala and I am doing this exercise where I need to create an interactive shell/console app where the user can introduce an OS path (as a string) to a directory and the program must return a list of all the files within it.

Any pointers as what Scala (or Java) packages I should use? Are there any simple examples of such an app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can don this without any external library by just suing the stdlib of both **Scala** and **Java**, although if you are interested this is a great exercise to use `IO` & `Stream` from **cats-effect** and **fs2**... but just check those if the programs as values paradigm interest you, and if so please consider joining the **typelevel** **discord** server for support.

Comment: Thanks, @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ;)

Comment: The simplest answer might be os-lib from li Haoyi